# How to change colour of single bar in Material UI when using BarChart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, material-ui

I'm using the following code to make a Graph:

```js
const namesArray = Object.values(tableData).map(item => item.name);
  const valuesArray = Object.values(tableData).map(item => item.value);

  return (
    <Box>
      <SimpleCard title="Cell Voltages">
        <BarChart
          width={750}
          height={300}
          series={[
            { data:valuesArray, id: 'cId'},
          ]}
          xAxis={[{ data: namesArray, scaleType: 'band' }]}
        />
      </SimpleCard>
    </Box>
  );
```

And I'm getting this as output:
[Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ9lt.png)

However, I need to change the colour of a particular bar in this graph (currently highest and lowest values), but I can't seem to find any way to do this. I also didn't understand the documentation of the API on their website properly. What should I do to get the result I want?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the color of specific bar but if you want then using css class `MuiBarElement-root` and give `nth-child()` and add your color value may it works.

Other then if you want to change all bars color then you can use colors attribute for give custom color

check here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwxeyu?file=Demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I just got two, use `nth` child instead.

```
sx={{
  "& .MuiBarElement-root:first-child": {
    fill: "red",
  },
  "& .MuiBarElement-root:last-child": {
    fill: "black",
   },
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming you have already created the chart and have access to its container element

// Get the container element of the chart
const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart-container');

// Assuming you have already created the chart using Material-UI BarChart

// Get the individual bars inside the chart
const bars = chartContainer.querySelectorAll('.recharts-bar-rectangles');

// Define the index of the bar you want to change the color for
const targetBarIndex = 0; // Change this to the index of the bar you want to target

// Define the color you want to change the bar to
const newColor = 'green'; // Change this to the desired color

// Check if the target bar index is valid
if (targetBarIndex >= 0 && targetBarIndex < bars.length) {
  // Access the target bar and update its style
  bars[targetBarIndex].style.fill = newColor;
} else {
  console.error('Invalid target bar index');`enter code here`
}
```